# Scala how to format scrambled data in proper order

Tags: scala

I have my data in text file which looks as follows

```
a,b,c,"d
ee"
1,2,3,"fo
ur"
p,o,t,"lu
ck"
o,n,e,"m
o
re"
```

I want to clean my data in such a way that my final output should be as 
follows:

```
a,b,c,"dee"
1,2,3,"four"
p,o,t,"luck"
o,n,e,"more"
```

This what I tried but I cant get what I was expecting:

```
val clean = Source.fromFile("my/path/csv/file.csv")
  .getLines
  .drop(1)
  .mkString
  .split("\"")
  .array
```

Can someone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is not too big:

```
Source.fromFile("my/path/csv/file.csv")
  .mkString                               // Iterator[String] to String
  .init                                   // Remove the last " as we're gooing to split on \"\n and the last one won't be removed
  .split("\"\n")                          // "a,b,c,\"d\nee\"\n1,2,3,\"fo becomes Array("a,b,c,\"d\nee", "1,2,3,\"fo")
  .map(_.replace("\n", "") + "\"")        // and we remove those wrongly placed \n
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
val clean = Source.fromFile("my/path/csv/file.csv")
  .getLines
  .foldLeft((List[String](), "")){ 
    case ((result, partial), line) => {
      val combined = partial + line
      if (combined.count(_ == '"') == 2) 
        (combined :: result, "") 
      else 
        (result, combined)
    }
  }._1.reverse
```